# Child items in flexbox layout expand outside of parent when there is too much text

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

First of all, I am working with React JS and trying to use the react-textfit module to allow the text to automatically fit within the div without the div expanding.

However, it never seems to work because the child items seem to keep expanding outside of the parent. I believe because of this the react-textfit module is never getting called.

So what it currently looks like is:

[image]

Notice how the flex children are expanding outside of the outer div (red box).

Here is a simplified form of my code (converted from React style to simple HTML/CSS):

```css
.parent {
 margin: 200px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
}

.outer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 background-color: white;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 10px;
 flex-direction: column;
 border: solid red 3px;
}

.inner {
 flex: 1;
 font-size: 20px;
 display: flex;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border: solid blue 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
   <Textfit mode="multi">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
   </Textfit>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
   <Textfit mode="multi">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
   </Textfit>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
   <Textfit mode="multi">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
   </Textfit>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First off, the `align-items: center;` is the reason it overflow both at top and bottom, and for that you need to use the `safe` keyword (or top/bottom auto margin). Second, what should happen to the text when it does overflow ? .. scroll, hide/cut off, ...?

Comment: @LGSon In simple CSS, I would just like it to get cutoff and not display a scrollbar. In reality, because I am using the React module, the text should autosize to fit the box anyhow.

Comment: Is the question about "auto-sizing" your text ?cause  I do not see overflow, nor text-ellipsis involved here.

Answer (score -1):

This will work fine as per your requirement

```
       .parent {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items:center;
        }

        .outer {
            width: 300px;
            height: auto;
            display: flex;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            flex-direction: column;
            border: solid red 3px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            position: absolute;
            top:0px
        }

        .inner {
            flex: 1;
            font-size: 40px;
            display: flex;
            text-align: center;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border: solid blue 1px;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: No, it is still expanding the outer div. Try changing font size to 40px to see what happens.

Comment: Hello @kojow7 Now you can change your font-size:anything; it is not going to break.

Comment: What do you mean? The divs are still getting bigger to fit the text.